# reset fieldset values in backbone.js

Tags: jquery, forms, backbone.js

I am having a fieldset in jQuery template:

```
<script id="tmpl_companies" type="x-jquery-tmpl">
    <fieldset id="add-row" class="clearfix">
        <div>
            <label for="industry_type">Industry Type: </label>
            <input type="text" id="industry_type" value="${industry_type}"><br/>
        </div>
        <div>
            <label for="hiring_company_name">Hiring_Company Name: </label>
            <input type="text" id="company_name" value=${hiring_company_name}><br/>
        </div>
        <div class="last">
            <button type="submit" id="save" name="save" alt="save" >
                <img src="/assets/img/add.png" />
            </button>
            <button type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" alt="reset" >
                <img src="/assets/img/cancel.png" />
            </button>
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</script>
```

How can I reset the fieldset values by clicking the reset button

```
'click #reset' : 'reset'
```

in backbone.js

```
reset: function() {
  ???????
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't handle this in backbone. Just let the browser reset the form for you, using the `<input type="reset">` button.

If you must use Backbone, just re-render the view:

```
  reset: function(){
    this.render();
  },

  render: function(){
    var html = $("#my-template").tmpl(this.model.toJSON());
    this.$el.html(html);
  }
```

Comment: But re-rendering the page causes that all **temporary content is lost**. In my case there is a callback message informing the user about the successful or failure submit of the form.

Comment: I'm right there with you JJD, plus the re-rendered form does not instantiate my JS datepicker properly and when added to render function it breaks, and does not work inside initialize. Any better solutions?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script id="tmpl_companies" type="x-jquery-tmpl">

<fieldset id="add-row" class="clearfix">
<form>  // missed here

<div><label for="industry_type">Industry Type: </label>
<input type="text" id="industry_type" value="${industry_type}"><br/>
</div>
<div><label for="hiring_company_name">Hiring_Company Name: </label>
<input type="text" id="company_name" value=${hiring_company_name}><br/>
</div>
<div class="last">
<button type="submit" id="save" name="save" alt="save" ><img src="/assets/img/add.png"    /></button>
<button type="reset" id="reset" name="reset" alt="reset" ><img src="/assets/img/cancel.png" /></button>

</div>
</form>  //missed here
</fieldset>
</script>
```